# R packages for performing topic modeling / LDA: just `topicmodels` and `lda`

Tags: r, bayesian, text-mining, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

It seems to me that only two R packages are able to perform *Latent Dirichlet Allocation*:

One is **`lda`**, authored by Jonathan Chang; and the other is **`topicmodels`** authored by Bettina Grün and Kurt Hornik.

What are the differences between these two packages, in terms of performance, implementation details and extensibility?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Implementation:
The topicmodels package provides an interface to the GSL C and C++ code for topic models by Blei et al. and Phan et al. For the earlier it uses Variational EM, for the latter Gibbs Sampling. See http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i13/paper . The package works well with the utilities from the tm package.

The lda package uses a collapsed Gibbs Sampler for a number of models similar to those from the GSL library. However, it has been implemented by the package authors itself, not by Blei et al. This implementation therefore differs in general from the estimation technique proposed in the original papers introducing these model variants, where the VEM algorithm is usually applied. On the other hand, the package offers more functionality then the other package.
The package provides text mining functionality too.

Extensibility:
Regarding extensibility, the topicmodel code by its very nature can be extended to interface other topic model code written in C and C++. The lda package seems to be more relying on the specific implementation provided by the authors, but there Gibbs sampler might allow specifying your own topic model. For extensibility issues nota bene, the former is licensed under GPL-2 and the latter LGPL, so it might depend on what you need to extend it for (GPL-2 is stricter regarding the open source aspect, i.e. you can't use it in proprietary software).

Performance:
I can't help you here, I only used topicmodels so far.

Conclusion:
Personally I use `topicmodels`, as it is well documented (see the JSS paper above) and I trust the authors (Grün also implemeted flexmix and Hornik is R core member).

Comment: First, I'm sure that topicmodels is an excellent package, and I agree that it is very well documented. Regarding "trusting" the authors of the LDA package, Jonathan Chang was my PhD student, and I completely trust his code. He is both an excellent software engineer and scholar. His package is easy, scales well to fairly large collections, and it is nice to explore the results in R. (I like and I'm used to the sparse matrix representation of documents.) Of note, LDA implements other models, including relational topic models, supervised LDA (with GLM), and mixed-membership stochastic blockmodel.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I'm sure the `lda` package is great, I didn't mean to imply that `lda` has somehow inferior code. I stated my personal impression (the documentation appeared a bit sloppy). Since that was >2 years ago I edited the answer slightly (the typos at the CRAN page are still there, I think it would be good for them to be fixed but that email seems to have gotten lost).

Comment: I guess you have a lot of experience with both packages and know most about the general topic, how about providing an answer listing some of the pros and cons of both packages? I didn't use `lda`, so I couldn't give an empirical assessment of it. Providing that would surely help the OP and everyone else as well as correct any possible injustices (which were not intended). Thanks!

Comment: I also tried both, and found the `lda` package to contain more options. However, it's difficult to understand how to format your data in order for it to fit into the model. The `topicmodels` package works well with the `tm` package, while the `lda` package requests a list which is not clear how to create.

Answer (score 12):

+1 for [topicmodels](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/). @Momo's answer is very comprehensive. I'd just add that `topicmodels` takes input as document term matrices, which are easily made with the `tm` package or using python. The `lda` package uses a more esoteric form of input (based on Blei's LDA-C) and I've had no luck using the built-in functions to convert dtm into the `lda` package format (the lda documentation is very poor, as Momo notes).

I have some code that starts with raw text, pre-processes it in `tm` and puts it through `topicmodels` (including finding the optimum number of topics in advance and working with the output) [here](https://github.com/benmarwick/AAA2011-Tweets). Could be useful to someone coming to `topicmodels` for the first time.

Comment: For those not already using *tm*, and wanting to play with *lda*, [JFreq](http://www.williamlowe.net/software/jfreq) also puts plain texts in LDA-C's preferred format.

Comment: Good to know about JFreq, I haven't seen it before. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just spotted the `read_dtm_Blei_et_al` function in the `tm` package which does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The  R Structural Topic Model (STM) package by  Molly Roberts, Brandon Stewart and Dustin Tingley is also a great choice. Built on top of the tm package it's a general framework for topic modeling with document-level covariate information.

http://structuraltopicmodel.com/

The STM package includes a series of methods (grid search) and measures (semantic coherence, residuals and exclusivity) to determine the number of topics. Setting the number of topics to 0 will also let the model determine an optimum number of topics.

The stmBrowser package is a great data visualization complement to visualize the influence of external variables on topics. See this example related to the 2016 presidential debates: http://alexperrier.github.io/stm-visualization/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I used all three libraries, among all 3 viz., topicmodels, lda, stm; not everyone works with n grams. The topicmodels library is good with its estimation and it also work with n grams. But if anyone is working with uni grams then the practitioner may preferred stm as it gives structured output.